# The Java servlet HttpSession does not seem to work immediately

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets

In my login servlet, the last code of `doPost` is as follows:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER, user);
request.getRequestDispatcher("app.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

What comes to `app.jsp`, it is as follows:

```
<%@page import="fi.vakuutustiedot.controllers.Config"%>
<%@page import="fi.vakuutustiedot.model.User"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    if (session == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }

    User user = (User) session.getAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER);

    if (user == null) {
        session.invalidate();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
        return;    
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

My problem is the following scenario:

1. I login through the HTML form that is connected to my login servlet.
2. The login servlet creates a `HttpSession` and adds an attribute for the object describing the user in question.
3. Finally, it forwards to `app.jsp`.

The problem is that when I am logged and forwarded to `app.jsp`, I see everything I am supposed to see, ***but*** if I type `.../app.jsp` in the location bar and press Enter it redirects to `index.html`! However, when I visit `app.jsp` the second, third, .etc time, everything is fine and no spurious redirect to `index.html` happens.

## Is this solution adequate from the security standpoint?

I resolved the issue by adding in the login servlet the following line:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
request.setAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER, user); // <- The new added line.
session.setAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER, user);
request.getRequestDispatcher("app.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And in `app.jsp` I have:

```
<%@page import="fi.vakuutustiedot.controllers.Config"%>
<%@page import="fi.vakuutustiedot.model.User"%>
<%@page import="fi.vakuutustiedot.model.UserType"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%! User user = null; %>
<%
    if (session == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("no_session.html").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }

    user = (User) session.getAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER);

    if (user == null) {
        user = (User) request.getAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER);
    }

    if (user == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

## Answering my own question

In the login servlet, all I do is:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_PARAMETER, user);
response.sendRedirect("app.jsp");
```

That way, the user object is available straight from the `session` and I do not need to put that user to the request object.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are trying to get to a page outside of your context.

By your question, I am only guessing your directory is:
/index.html
/app.jsp

When you are running your application, you probably inter a URI such as:
http://[my_server]/[my_app]/index.html
or just:
http://[my_server]/[my_app]/

When you type ../app.jsp, your are trying to get something that is not there. Your server is probably set to send a default page of index.html with no default error page.

I am guessing you are just getting back the index.html page because of the incorrect URI.